# Merge [d2] into [d]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Backstory: Before 2007, there was only one major version of the D programming language. Version 2, which appeared in 2007, was a major breaking change and took a while to stabilize, which meant that projects existed for both language versions for a while (thus people often used D1 and D2 to distinguish the major language versions).

Today, D1 is long abandoned and almost completely unused, there being only one major version worth discussing. Thus, the "2" in the [d2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d2) tag is now redundant.

Out of the 336 questions tagged [d2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d2), only one is not also tagged [d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d): [issues configuring G-WAN to use D2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171582/issues-configuring-g-wan-to-use-d2). Thus, [d2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d2) can either be merged into [d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d) or just deleted (and that one question retagged).

Comment: And what about when D3 comes along? *(other than the confusion with the JavaScript visualization library :P)*

Comment: There is no D3 on the horizon, no plans and no preparations. Language forks have shown to be very detrimental to the language's health, so it is very unlikely to ever happen.

Comment: Is there anything I should do aside from posting this? Such as flagging this question for moderator attention so that a moderator executes the merge?

Comment: @moderators: what is the procedure to go ahead with this? Imho Vladimir has made a strong case.

Comment: Merged the tags. In 2019, that was still the only question which did not have the [d] tag.

Comment: I've now updated the usage guidance on [dmd](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8594949/revisions) and [d](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3616052/revisions).